# Netbeans 8.2 JFrame form source code created from eventsactionperformed not working

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I recently made a GUI program for the programming course that I am taking, and I created many components including buttons. I then tried to add an event to one of the buttons I have created, and then when I try to double click on it and go into the source code to change what happens when it is clicked, the event that I wanted to happen for the button was not appearing. So for example, there was no "testButtonActionPerormed class anywhere in the code. I have encountered this problem many times and I have no clue on how to fix it. Any tips are appreciated. Here is the full code... (Note the button that I tried to add the event to is called "initializeButton")

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/**
 *
 * 
 */
public class CDCollectionGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form CDCollectionGUI */
    public CDCollectionGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Generated Code ">//GEN-BEGIN:initComponents
    private void initComponents() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        pack();
    }
    // </editor-fold>//GEN-END:initComponents

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CDCollectionGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CDCollectionGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CDCollectionGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CDCollectionGUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new CDCollectionGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify//GEN-BEGIN:variables
    // End of variables declaration//GEN-END:variables

}
```

Comment: Your code isn't even showing the button being added to the form. Could you provide the exact steps in how you create the form and add the button?

Comment: Are you looking at the source in netbeans after adding the event?  Just checking you aren't viewing the source in a separate text editor?  The changes won't be visible outside of netbeans until you press save.